# Form creation interface and simple back-end, should I go for CMS or is there a better option?

Tags: forms, content-management-system

I often need to create similar, but very long HTML forms for a client. The forms contain some inter-dependent fields and lot of validations. Some images also need to be uploaded.

Then the client needs to check the database in the CPanel and export it from there.

I want to create something with easy interface which can create complicated forms. Also, client is asking for easy-to-operate back end. The CMS option looks like an overkill. I want to keep the site as lightweight as possible because of performance requirement.

Please suggest me the best path I should take. Should I try to develop everything from scratch? Should I use a CMS? Is there any particular CMS more suitable for the task?

Answer (score 0):

We use [ChronoForms](http://www.chronoengine.com/) along with Joomla 3.1 to create such forms. It has two modes, an easier one that limits the functionality but creation of forms is much easier. The other one offers the full capabilities of the engine but requires manual steps to do even simple things.

Having said that, ChronoForms is the most powerful web based forms designer I have come across. It seems they also support Wordpress now.

They have a drag-drop mechanism to design the forms. Validations are easy to do via check boxes for the standard ones. You can save the results into database tables, send emails, redirect users to specific pages, add captchas.

The backend allows you to view the records and create new tables based on the fields of the form. You can also export the result as CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It looks like a good option. But I would really like to keep the site light. I don't like idea of using Joomla for a single form. I am looking for something lighter and more simple.